# Compiling a .ts file to .js for Typescrpit version 3.2 and above

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How to compile a .ts file to .js file using Typescript version 3.2 and above as tsc.exe is not present fr version 3.2 and above.

We are using tsc.exe to compile all the .ts files in our project but while migrating to typescript 3.2 and above not sure how to do the same.

Following blog talks about absence to tsc.exe from typescript 3.2 version and onwards-

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-2-rc/

This Code works for Typescript version 3.1 if run on command prompt-
C:\Typescript\3.1\tsc Hello.ts

But it doesn't work for Typescript version 3.2 and above due to absence of tsc.exe

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to install TypeScript CLI Node.js module. Assuming you have Node.js installed just type in your shell:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and then you can compile any .ts file like:

```
tsc Hello.ts
```

Comment: -How can I do that using any of the build tools any idea? If I want to run the tsc command from a specific folder it won't work due to absence of tsc.exe as mentioned above-  'C:\Typescript\3.1\tsc Hello.ts'.   Globally yeah it would work but I want it specific to a folder I mean pointing the commad to a folder as mentioned above.

Comment: This install tsc globally so it will always work. If you don't want to install it globally you can install it to a specific folder without the -g flag like npm install  typescript and  run it from installDir/node_modules/.bin/tsc For example let's say thay you do npm i typescript in C:\Typescript you could run tsc like C:\Typescript\node_modules\.bin\tsc Hello.ts